# Embed twitter feed with CSP

Tags: twitter, content-security-policy

I'm using the following CSP

```
    header("Content-Security-Policy: object-src 'none'; style-src 'self' 'strict-dynamic' ; script-src 'nonce-".$this->pageData->corsNonce['mainJS']."' 'nonce-".$this->pageData->corsNonce['twitterFeed']."' 'strict-dynamic' ; frame-src https://platform.twitter.com/ https://www.google.com/recaptcha/ https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/releases/tftmXwdbgCvrXiHxr5HGbIaL/;  default-src 'self' https://platform.twitter.com/ https://www.".$GLOBALS['PS']->siteNameNonWWW." 'strict-dynamic';");
```

the only way i can get it to work is by making the style "unsafe-inline" which basically means the CSP is pointless.

I have added this as per the twitter docs `<meta content="on" name="twitter:widgets:csp">`

Im still getting all these errors

```
widgets.js:8 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' https://syndication.twitter.com/ https://platform.twitter.com/ 'strict-dynamic'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-nBgB6cwZqnfrMp3dIoMlryBNMGi3lqt6zDfOlsM/uwQ='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.

(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ timeline.55167c7072ca7f4363bf18820295ba93.js:1
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
c.render @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:1
6Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' <URL> <URL> 'strict-dynamic'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-3zC5aZ7mL1/H7Okaxa0bNmOgHvkG9IwnFWdzK9sV4ek='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.

widgets.js:8 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' https://syndication.twitter.com/ https://platform.twitter.com/ 'strict-dynamic'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-W8ZPF9qOhYdwnWllgm0/H0Nza2RB+2lL4/NcSDMURYM='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.

(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ timeline.55167c7072ca7f4363bf18820295ba93.js:1
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
c.render @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:1
widgets.js:8 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' https://syndication.twitter.com/ https://platform.twitter.com/ 'strict-dynamic'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-RTBZ4ChJJI5KtanbP4/OuMgGOQk1cqFU203V48mWRMw='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.

(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ timeline.55167c7072ca7f4363bf18820295ba93.js:1
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
c.render @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:1
widgets.js:8 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' https://syndication.twitter.com/ https://platform.twitter.com/ 'strict-dynamic'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-RTBZ4ChJJI5KtanbP4/OuMgGOQk1cqFU203V48mWRMw='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.

(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ timeline.55167c7072ca7f4363bf18820295ba93.js:1
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
c.render @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:1
widgets.js:8 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' https://syndication.twitter.com/ https://platform.twitter.com/ 'strict-dynamic'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-AiIIJTmp6KuDsDcbYjHAPgdi2KRwfho027VuZVwIjF0='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.

(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ timeline.55167c7072ca7f4363bf18820295ba93.js:1
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
c.render @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:1
widgets.js:8 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' https://syndication.twitter.com/ https://platform.twitter.com/ 'strict-dynamic'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-nBgB6cwZqnfrMp3dIoMlryBNMGi3lqt6zDfOlsM/uwQ='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.

(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ timeline.55167c7072ca7f4363bf18820295ba93.js:1
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
c.render @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:1
widgets.js:8 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' https://syndication.twitter.com/ https://platform.twitter.com/ 'strict-dynamic'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-vzjrJFpozgOR+wRUV14btg0zyQfVPaJEKBx102w/Rfk='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.

(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ timeline.55167c7072ca7f4363bf18820295ba93.js:1
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
c.render @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:1
widgets.js:8 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' https://syndication.twitter.com/ https://platform.twitter.com/ 'strict-dynamic'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-nBgB6cwZqnfrMp3dIoMlryBNMGi3lqt6zDfOlsM/uwQ='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.

(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ timeline.55167c7072ca7f4363bf18820295ba93.js:1
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
c.render @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:1
widgets.js:8 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' https://syndication.twitter.com/ https://platform.twitter.com/ 'strict-dynamic'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-nBgB6cwZqnfrMp3dIoMlryBNMGi3lqt6zDfOlsM/uwQ='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.

(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ timeline.55167c7072ca7f4363bf18820295ba93.js:1
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
c.render @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:1
87Refused to load the image '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' <URL> 'strict-dynamic'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

widgets.js:8 Refused to load the stylesheet 'https://ton.twimg.com/tfw/css/syndication_bundle_v1_73385286cca9d2256f6bf3993470820d4827b058.css' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' https://syndication.twitter.com/ https://platform.twitter.com/ 'strict-dynamic'". Note that 'style-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'style-src' is used as a fallback.

(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:1
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:1
o.run @ widgets.js:8
o.flush @ widgets.js:8
o.runBatch @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
i @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
requestAnimationFrame (async)
o.loop @ widgets.js:8
o.schedule @ widgets.js:8
o.scheduleBatch @ widgets.js:8
o.write @ widgets.js:8
write @ widgets.js:1
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ timeline.55167c7072ca7f4363bf18820295ba93.js:1
i @ widgets.js:1
(anonymous) @ timeline.55167c7072ca7f4363bf18820295ba93.js:1
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ timeline.55167c7072ca7f4363bf18820295ba93.js:1
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ timeline.55167c7072ca7f4363bf18820295ba93.js:1
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
c.render @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:1
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
i @ widgets.js:1
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
s._flush @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:1
h @ widgets.js:8
characterData (async)
w @ widgets.js:8
o @ widgets.js:8
s.add @ widgets.js:8
addWidget @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
g @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
Promise.then (async)
w @ widgets.js:8
loadPage @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
o @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
i @ widgets.js:1
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:1
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:1
widgets.js:8 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' https://syndication.twitter.com/ https://platform.twitter.com/ 'strict-dynamic'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-1eNW3sA4kFhE/L1XqcPKTI+WEaM0DkVXQdBZ3wredo8='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:1
o.run @ widgets.js:8
o.flush @ widgets.js:8
o.runBatch @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
i @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
widgets.js:8 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' https://syndication.twitter.com/ https://platform.twitter.com/ 'strict-dynamic'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-DdW8fWwumDjO9065QATtOV60fImuwIMEyMbaepWLUSo='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:1
o.run @ widgets.js:8
o.flush @ widgets.js:8
o.runBatch @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
i @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
/#nftpeel:1 Uncaught (in promise) Event {isTrusted: true, type: 'error', target: link, currentTarget: null, eventPhase: 0, …}
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ timeline.55167c7072ca7f4363bf18820295ba93.js:1
i @ widgets.js:1
(anonymous) @ timeline.55167c7072ca7f4363bf18820295ba93.js:1
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ timeline.55167c7072ca7f4363bf18820295ba93.js:1
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ timeline.55167c7072ca7f4363bf18820295ba93.js:1
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
c.render @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:1
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
i @ widgets.js:1
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
s._flush @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:1
h @ widgets.js:8
characterData (async)
w @ widgets.js:8
o @ widgets.js:8
s.add @ widgets.js:8
addWidget @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
g @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
Promise.then (async)
w @ widgets.js:8
loadPage @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
o @ widgets.js:8
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:8
i @ widgets.js:1
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:1
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:1
```

How is it possible to add a nonce to a twitter feed's inline style?

Why does the twitter meta CSP on not do anything despite the developer docs saying to use it?

This is really annoying me.

Thanks in advance.